# Ignore data within a certain set of characters with PHP

Tags: php, function, preg-match, echo, file-get-contents

Not sure what this is called, but is there a way I can pull data from a file, echo it, but ignore data within a certain set of characters?

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('test.txt');
?>
```

[image]

Would it be possible to ignore the data in between the asterisks, and the asterisks themselves when I echo out the final function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't "ignore it" as much as you would "replace it with nothing"

A quick 'n' dirty approach

```
echo preg_replace( "/\*{3}.*?\*{3}/", "", file_get_contents( 'test.txt' ) );
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Now with that, I can experiment with other strings.

Comment: Note that this regex would be "greedy", so "this *** some text *** is a *** other text *** test" would come out as "this test", rather than "this is a test", as you may expect.

Comment: No it's not.  I specifically and deliberately made the subpattern ungreedy.  And I believe the test string you intended to indicated is `"this *** some text *** is a *** other text *** test"`